# ViewBinding in RecyclerView along with DiffUtils callback isn't working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

I'm trying to update/notify the adapter based on a value from the API call I get and I do have a DiffUtil callback in my adapter for the same. If I use viewBinding UI is not showing up but if I do use findViewById like this it seems to be working fine. Any help/leads appreciated. Thank you!

```
//ViewBinding ain't working along with DiffUtils for Some reason

    (view?.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView).apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            adapter = temListAdapter
    }

    updateAdapter()
    with(binding) {
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(this@ALFragment)
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this@ALFragment)
        header.headerText.setOnClickListener(this@ALFragment)
        header.headerRightArrow.setOnClickListener(this@ALFragment)
    }
```

This Is how I am binding in this current Fragment

```
private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentConfirmBinding::bind)
```

And this is the ViewBinding Util class for the fragments am using

```
class FragmentViewBinding<T : ViewBinding>(val fragment: Fragment, val viewBindingFactory: (View) -> T) : ReadOnlyProperty<Fragment, T> {
    private var binding: T? = null

    init {
        // Note: There's an open issue of memory leaks with view binding in fragments
        // Solution: Destroying binding on fragment destroy thus observing fragment's lifecycle to clear binding when fragment is destroyed
        fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observe(fragment, {
                    it.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
                        override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                            // clear this binding value when the views are destroyed
                            binding = null
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    }

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        val bindingRef = binding
        if (bindingRef != null) return bindingRef
        val lifecycle = fragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle
        if (!lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.INITIALIZED)) {
            throw IllegalStateException(FRAGMENT_KILLED_EXCEPTION_TEXT)
        }
        return viewBindingFactory(thisRef.requireView()).also { binding = it }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val FRAGMENT_KILLED_EXCEPTION_TEXT = "Should not attempt to get bindings when Fragment views are destroyed."
    }
}

/**
 * Extension method for fragment view binding
 */
fun <T : ViewBinding> Fragment.viewBinding(viewBindingFactory: (View) -> T) = FragmentViewBinding(this, viewBindingFactory)
```

Comment: can you post the whole adapter code, it would be helpful to figure out

Comment: Added @rahat Thanks

Comment: You can use optional backing field and a non-optional val which is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView to avoid memory leaks in fragments.
In onCreateView the optional backing field is set and in onDestroyView it is cleared.

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni This works using LifecycleAwareLazy instead as well without the optional backing approach. Anyways now it works totally fine with the DiffUtils as well after updating Kotlin version .